# Scala continuations not compiling

Tags: scala, continuations

I am trying Scala's continuation library (using Scala 2.12.10). The code that I am testing - to check whether I understand the concept - is as follows:

```
object Test {

  import scala.util.continuations._

  def run(): (Unit => Unit)  = {
    var x = 0;
    reset {
      while (x < 10) {
        if (x == 5)
          shift { cont: (Unit => Unit) =>
            return cont
          }
        println(f"x = $x")
        x += 1
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val cont = run()
    cont()
  }

}
```

The code I am trying was meant do break out of the while loop and allow the caller to call the continuation to resume the loop. However, I am getting an error:

> Error:(9, 9) type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Unit
>   @scala.util.continuations.cpsParam[Unit,Nothing]
>           if (x == 5)

I suspect I have to add `@scala.util.continuations.cpsParam[Unit,Nothing]` somewhere, but after trying in random places, I have no idea where it should be placed. **How can my code be corrected so that it compiles?**

My `build.sbt`:

```
name := "continuations"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

autoCompilerPlugins := true


libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-lang.plugins" %% "scala-continuations-library" % "1.0.3"

addCompilerPlugin(
"org.scala-lang.plugins" % "scala-continuations-plugin_2.12.0" % "1.0.3")
scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the code work by adding the `else` branch to the condition inside the `reset` and setting the return type of `run` to `Any`. I think the problem has something to do with types returned from different branches of code inside `run` not agreeing, but I had really no idea, if there is a one more concrete than `Any` that can be used to make the thing work.

```
object Test {

  import scala.util.continuations._

  def run():Any = {
    var x = 0;
    reset {

      while (x < 10) {
        if (x == 5)
          shift { cont: (Unit => Unit) =>
            return cont
          } else shift { cont: (Unit => Unit) =>
            cont()
          }
        println(f"x = $x")
        x += 1
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val cont = run()
    printf("Continuation called\n")
    cont.asInstanceOf[Unit=>Unit]()
  }

}
```